# Сохранить экран как изображение или PDF

Tags: c#, xamarin, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

В приложении есть экраны, унаследованные от `ContentPage`. Есть ли какие-то способы представить эти экраны в виде изображений либо PDF-файлов или страниц? Т.е. что-то типа скриншота.

Comment: [Taking a Screenshot in Xamarin.Forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/taking-a-screenshot-in-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score -1):

Не уверена, но скорее всего у контролов на ксамарине так же должна быть функция DrawToBitmap

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);//создаем картинку нужных размеров

panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);//копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp

bmp.Save("E:\\somePanelImage.bmp");    //ну и дальше просто сохраняем
```

По крайней мере в библиотеках Mono такая функция имеется. Значит, по логике, на ксамарине можно сделать точно то же самое. Ну и вместо последней строки уже заганяешь изображение куда тебе вздумается, хоть в пдф, хоть куда-то на телефон в виде просто картинки.

Собственно, ты просто родительский контрол так и скриншотишь. Вот и вся задача.

Comment: Нет в xamarin такого метода.